# Segfault in c program

Tags: c

I have a segmentation fault upon executing this program and all I know is that segfault is happening after two of the gets commands and after the next scanf command. I know gets isn't good command to use in here but my university is using it so... Here is the code of my main function and functions that program uses and I would appreciate if someone could said to me where the problem persists. The code is written in croatian but nothing really particular isnt said in there so don't mind that

My main program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "funkcije.h"
#define MAX 300

int main (void) {
    char niz1[MAX+1], podniz[6], niz2[MAX+1];
    int dulj_pod = 0, kontrola, duljina1 = 0, duljina2 = 0, kraj, brojac = 0, i;
    float slicnost;
    printf("Ucitaj prvi niz > ");
    gets(niz1);
    printf("Ucitaj drugi niz > ");
    gets(niz2);
    while (niz1[duljina1] != '\0')
        duljina1++;
    while (niz2[duljina2] != '\0')
        duljina2++;
    printf("Ucitaj duljinu podniza : ");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &dulj_pod);
    } while ((dulj_pod < 2 || dulj_pod > 5) || (dulj_pod > duljina1 || dulj_pod > duljina2));
    kraj = duljina1 - dulj_pod;
    for (i=0; i<=kraj; i++) {
        genPodniz (niz1, podniz, i, dulj_pod);
        kontrola = sadrziPodniz (niz2, podniz);
        if (kontrola == 1)
            brojac++;
    }
    slicnost = (float)brojac / (kraj+1);
    printf("Prvi niz : %s\nDrugi niz : %s\nDuljina podniza za usporedbu nizova : %d\n", niz1, niz2, dulj_pod);
    printf("Slicnost nizova '%s' i '%s' iznosi %f.\n", niz1, niz2, slicnost);
    return 0;
}'
```

And functions

```
#include "funkcije.h"

void genPodniz (char *niz, char *podNiz, int pocPozicija, int duljPodniz) {
    int i, j=0;
    for (i=0; i<duljPodniz; i++, j++) {
        *(podNiz+j) = *(niz+pocPozicija+i);
    }
    *(podNiz+j) = '\0';
}

int sadrziPodniz (char *niz, char *podNiz) {
    int kontrola, i = 0, j = 0, duljina1 = 0, duljina2 = 0, poz = 0;
    while (*(niz+duljina1) != '\0')
        duljina1++; 
    while (*(niz+duljina2) != '\0')
        duljina2++;
    while (j < duljina2) {
        if (*(niz+i) == *(podNiz+j)) {
            kontrola = 1;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            kontrola = 0;
            j = 0;
            ++poz;
            i = poz;
        }
    } 
    return kontrola;
}
```

Comment: `gets` is obsolete and dangerous. Never use it (at least, use `fgets`, or preferably `getline`, or perhaps `readline`). Then, compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`), and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

Comment: So, why don't you use a debugger to check where it's segfaulting and why?

Comment: `for (i=0; i<=kraj; i++) {` the `<=` is suspect.

Comment: Gee, thank you so much for writing the description at the top of the question in English!

Comment: What input do you use when the program crashes? You should also try to provide a _minimal_, compilable example that still shows the same problem.

Comment: `if (*(niz+i) == *(podNiz+j)) {` BTW: most people prefer array indexing for readability : `if (niz[i] == podNiz[j]) {`

Comment: @Martin: When I tried to run the program, it crashed on the line that wildplasser mentions. The variable i was 2512 and j was 0. A debugger is a very useful tool!

Comment: how could i be 2512 if it is initialized with i=0 at the beginning of for

Comment: And **use the standard library functions** (at least for clarity) `while (*(niz+duljina1) != '\0') duljina1++; ` -- > `duljina1 = strlen (niz);` etc (there is also a strcpy() // memcpy /memmove somewhere below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - find out how to run this code under a debugger. Then it'll just stop on the line where the segfault occurs, which should make it more-obvious what the problem is. Given that you're saying "segfault", it's probably safe to assume you're running some unix-variant, in which case, "gdb" is probably your debugger.

Second - a segfault is, maybe 90% of the time, due to overrunning the bounds of allocated memory. Since your program isn't allocating any memory with "malloc", that means you're writing past the end of one of your arrays. Chances are, one of your loops is running *way* too many times, and accessing past the end of an array.

Comment: Found a problem, the problem was in if condition in functions that than dragged some other minor problems.